# mysql how to use column count when same column can have 2 different values

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have an cutomer table where i store some customer error data
I would like to find different count on the same column.

```
Errorid  custName   ErrorReported
----------------------------------
1         abc       Dead_battery
2         xyz       Low_voltage
3         ann       Dead_battery
4         ben       Dead_battery
5         max       Low_voltage
```

The result of sql query should be count and ErrorReportedtype

```
count(*)    Errortype
------------------------
3           Dead_battery       
2           Low_voltage
```

Answer (score 1):

If you group by the column to be unique you can use aggregate functions like `count` on every group

```
select count(*), ErrorReported as ErrorType
from your_table
group by ErrorReported
```